# Как поднять производительность обновления сцены QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, оптимизация

Написал вот такой код:

.h

```
#ifndef STATEBALANSER_H
#define STATEBALANSER_H
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <memorymap.h>

class StateBalanser : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    StateBalanser(int num);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

    void StateBalance();

    void setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2);

    void setColorText(QColor text);

    void setFontText(QFont fontText);

private:
    unsigned char colorState;

    unsigned char colorMode;

    int number;

    QRectF _intersect;

    QColor _fillColorState;

    QColor _fillColorModeWork;

    QColor _fillColorText;

    QFont  _fontText;

public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    QPainterPath shape() const;
};

#endif // STATEBALANSER_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "statebalanser.h"

StateBalanser::StateBalanser(int num) :
    number(num)
{
    setColorState(10,10); // 10 10
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    StateBalanser::StateBalance();

    StateBalanser::setColorText(Qt::black);

    StateBalanser::setFontText(QFont("Monospace", 10));

    setToolTip(QString("Sensor %1").arg(number + 1));
}


void StateBalanser::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->fillRect(boundingRect(), _fillColorModeWork);

    painter->fillRect(_intersect, _fillColorState);

    painter->drawPath(shape());

    painter->setFont(_fontText);

    painter->setPen(_fillColorText);

    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString("%1").arg(number + 1) );
 }


void StateBalanser::StateBalance()
{
    _intersect = boundingRect().intersected(QRectF(3, 3, 44, 32));
}


void StateBalanser::setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2)
{ 
    switch(value_2)
    {
    case StopBalancer :        _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
    break;

    case ChargeBalancer :      _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#0000ff") ;
    break;

    case DischargeBalancer :   _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ff0000") ;
    break;

    case EsrBalancer :         _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#32CD32") ;
    break;

    case DisconnectBalancer :  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
    break;

    default :                  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
    break;
    }

    switch(value_1)
    {
    case StateGood :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#99FF99") ;
    break;

    case  StateFiftyFifty: _fillColorState =  QColor("#FFFF66") ;
    break;

    case StateFault :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#FF9999")  ;
    break;

    case StateDisconnect:  _fillColorState =  QColor("#999999") ;
    break;

    default :              _fillColorState =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
    break;
    }
}

void StateBalanser::setColorText(QColor text)
{
    _fillColorText =  QColor(text);
}

void StateBalanser::setFontText(QFont fontText)
{
    _fontText = fontText;
}

QRectF StateBalanser::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0, 0, 49, 37);
}

QPainterPath StateBalanser::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;

    path.addRect(boundingRect());

    return path;
}
```

В конструкторе mainwindow :

```
graphicsScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    statebalanser = new StateBalanser(i);
    statebalanser->setPos((i * 54) % 540, (i / 10) * 42);
    graphicsScene->addItem(statebalanser);
}

ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(graphicsScene);
```

Делаю обновление :

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> items = graphicsScene->items(Qt::AscendingOrder);

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    dynamic_cast<StateBalanser*>(items.at(i))->setColorState(massifDataBalansir[i].State, massifDataBalansir[i].modeWork);
}

graphicsScene->update();
items.clear();
```

Проблема в долгом обновление. Занимает пример 400 мс. при загрузки процессора на 100% период обновления 1 секунда.  Как можно ускорить обновление ? Или выводить не все сразу объекты а по одному или несколько?

Comment: Ну типо ты 2D пишешь, да? если да то лучше SFML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь и самое главное, что сразу бросается в глаза это вот:

```
painter->fillRect(boundingRect().intersected(QRectF(3, 3, 44, 32)), fillColor);
```

Поиск пересечения двух прямоугольников это довольно "тяжелая" операция.
Заведите переменную, отвечающую за пересечение и вычисляйте ее где-нибудь в другом месте, вне метода отрисовки. Сейчас это, например, в конструкторе, но если вы будете менять положение item-ма, то в методе изменения положения:

```
class StateBalanser ... {
public:
    StateBalance() {
        _intersect = boundingRect().intersected(QRectF(3, 3, 44, 32));
    }
    void paint(...) {
        painter->fillRect(_intersect, fillColor);
    }

private:
    QRect _intersect;
    QColor _fillColorState;
    QColor _fillColorMode;
}
```

Второе, выбор цвета (оба свича) перенесете туда, где вы этот цвет устанавливаете, - нет никакой необходимости постоянно делать выбор в paint. Метод `setColorState`:

```
void StateBalanser::setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2)
{
    switch(value_2)
    {   
    case StopBalancer : _fillColorMode =  QColor("#000000") ;
    break;
    case ChargeBalancer : _fillColorMode =  QColor("#0000ff") ;
    break;
    case DischargeBalancer : _fillColorMode =  QColor("#ff0000") ;
    break;
    case EsrBalancer : _fillColorMode =  QColor("#32CD32") ;
    break;
    case DisconnectBalancer : _fillColorMode =  QColor("#000000") ;
    break;
    default : _fillColorMode =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
    }
    // Для _fillColorState аналогично
}
```

Comment: Что сделал добавил в вопросе. Улучшилось но все равно немного тормозит.

Comment: @zhilenkov какое у вас железо? Видеокарта, проц, памяти сколько?

Comment: У меня arm imx287 память DDR2 видеокарты как бы нет.

Comment: меня в принципе устраивают небольшие тормоза. Можно с вами поговорить по поводу интерфейса в graphicsView ? Меня интересует 'ScrollBar'.

Comment: @zhilenkov задайте вопрос на SO, кто-нибудь ответит

Comment: Заметил что много отбирают ресурсов методы '    painter->setFont(_fontText);
    painter->setPen(_fillColorText);
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString("%1").arg(number + 1) ' подскажите как можно их оптимизировать?

Comment: @zhilenkov Они устанавливаются в паинтер в методе рисования, следовательно,  если их надо установливать один раз, то просто просто заведите условный флаг

Comment: можно попросить пример ?

Comment: @zhilenkov можно, но в понедельник. Компьютера под рукой нет

Comment: @ Alexander Chernin вы хотя бы наводку дайте. А дальше я сам.

Comment: @zhilenkov так дал уже

Comment: Ну так если я применю условный флаг к ' painter->setFont(_fontText);

    painter->setPen(_fillColorText);

    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString("%1").arg(number + 1) ); ', то у меня пропадет текст в моих прямоугольниках на следующем этапе обновления сцены. Понимает у меня сцена обновляется раз в 10 секунд. Обновляются только цвета внутри прямоугольника.

Comment: @zhilenkov  скоро напишу как надо сделать